# select parent category first then child

Tags: categories

Hello I'm trying to select parent category first then the child
My code on template look like this

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['prop_category']) ) {
$prop_category_selected  =   intval($_POST['prop_category']);
}
if( isset($_POST['prop_action_category']) ) {
$prop_action_category_selected  =   intval($_POST['prop_action_category']);
}
if( isset( $_GET['listing_edit'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['listing_edit']) ) {
$edit_id = intval( $_GET['listing_edit'] );
$prop_category                  =   get_the_terms( $edit_id, 'property_category');
if(!empty($prop_category)){
foreach ($prop_category as $key=>$term){
       $prop_category_selected=intval($term->term_id);
   }
}else{
 $prop_category_selected = -1;
}

$prop_category                  =   get_the_terms( $edit_id, 'property_action_category');
if(!empty($prop_category)){
    foreach ($prop_category as $key=>$term){
        $prop_action_category_selected=intval($term->term_id);
    }
}else{
  $prop_action_category_selected = -1;
}
}
?>

<?php if(   is_array($wpestate_submission_page_fields) && in_array('prop_category', $wpestate_submission_page_fields)) { ?>
            <p class="col-md-6"><label for="prop_category"><?php esc_html_e('Category','wpresidence');?></label>
                <?php
                    $args=array(
                            'class'       => 'select-submit2',
                            'hide_empty'  => false,
                            'selected'    => $prop_category_selected,
                            'name'        => 'prop_category',
                            'id'          => 'prop_category_submit',
                            'orderby'     => 'NAME',
                            'order'       => 'ASC',
                            'show_option_none'   => esc_html__('None','wpresidence'),
                            'taxonomy'    => 'property_category',
                            'hierarchical'=> true
                        );
                    wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
            </p>
        <?php }?>
```

thank you in advance